# CakePHP Grid View with filtering, column exclusion and AJAX Pagination

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm working on building a grid or spreadsheet View in CakePHP.  The View uses Pagination via AJAX in the standard CakePHP way.

I need to add in some standard spreadsheet functionality:

- hide or show columns
- apply filters with user provided criteria and operands
- save filters

Looking at the XHR that view is currently generating I'm thinking that I need to extend the Paginator Controller and Helper to alter the requests.  I'm looking for input on whether this is the right approach, as well as any guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To show and hide your column if you want to do this with js I suggest CakeGrid Plugin:

https://github.com/Mehrdad-Dadkhah/CakeGrid

or use jquery DataTable like this example : http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

but I suggest CakeGrid plugin because it make your grid clean and give you a lot of options and tow layout for Grid include table and div and ...

to have ajax paginate and filter both together you can add a form to filtering and

save last paginate options in session and manage filtering with last paginate option in your controller

or

when fire your ajax event on success replace action of filtering form with last requested url. you can do this if handle ajax yourself and disable seurity check for your action because you change form action and you get CSRF error from cake security component